# Is there a way to record user's activity offline and update them when they online?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, html

I just want to allow users make modification offline with insecure data. Namely modifying their profile name, add new content (page), photos and so forth. When they come online all these activities must be updated accordingly in the online server.

I need some vast ideas on this. It's going to be a web app, mostly sort of personal website.If I were to do this app, should I ensure they have mysql and wamp server installed so that offline changes can be recorded in the local host?

I refer to few forums and some of them mentioning html5 localstorage. Here's one of them: [Mobile site/app - capture data offline and push to live database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8729624/mobile-site-app-capture-data-offline-and-push-to-live-database)

The site to be developed mainly in PHP, MYSQL, HTML5 and JQUERY.

Comment: you can try to use local storage but i am not sure what the  downside of using local storage for this matter

Comment: I am about to hit the sack but localStorage will take you close to where you want to be. The main drawback is localStorage will only accept strings, so doing some json parsing and decoding back and forth would help.

Comment: @Jesse he also wants to have photos saving blob on local storage isn't a bad idea right?he can do that for photos.

Comment: Hey guys what about HTML5 application caching? How good or bad it is compared to localstorage?

Comment: You answered your own question. @Pekka There is probably a better solution. Let the question simmer. In localStorage you get around 5mb by default on most browsers so saving something in there for a few minutes when they pop offline (maybe when their internet goes out) is not entirely a bad idea.

Comment: But hey, I'm thinking to allow the user to come back online even after 1 week or 1 month being offline! SO in this case localstorage won't help? Database must come in here, I guess but how do I go about it? SHall I ensure the user install apache server with mysql first in the localhost?

Comment: If giving instructions to your user on how to install (i.e:) XAMPP is a viable solution, than all you need is a couple of lines of PHP to write-to-file (like some sort of database) and create / delete folders and files. Than using AJAX you contact using POST your PHP functions and you have a small flat-file database - even to store images in Base64 (as string). All that is quite easy if you find MySQL over-the-top for you / installation / and the end-user - and the 5MB of localStorage seem not enough.

Comment: I'm not sure Application Cache might suit your needs - since it's basically used to store your web-pages on the user's machine.

Comment: @Vani User could save page to local file system , modify saved page locally , upload to server when online to sync version ?

Comment: @guest271314 I think that should work by default under-the-hood.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan If interpret correctly , yes ; utilizing `download` attribute , `URL.createObjectURL()` ,  `$.post()`

Comment: @guest271314 OK, but $.post and save *Where* if the page is offline (and localstorage keeps only ~5mb depending on browser.)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan  what about PHP desktop for dekstop app but how do I sync all data when goes online? Or should I create an API?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Save , modify page to local file system using `download` attribute for when offline , not local storage ; post modified page to server when online ; `html` `download` attribute

Comment: @guest271314 Silly. I don't think users will do what you think they will do (-> save every single change they do on an app page like "My Settings" and than expect the user to upload them back on the page when they are online.)

Comment: @Vani Yes, you can use PHP Desktop instead of XAMPP, WAMPP or other

Comment: @Vani what about using LocalStorage any way? If the user is offline you can show a bar on the top of the screen that shows how much data is stored inside localstorage. When they reach 5MB you can tell them "OK Enough data for now - wait a bit till you get an internet connection"

Comment: @Vani if what you're building is for you and your friends - than install whatever you want to play with. They'll not argue since are friends, but you cannot expect a non-IT-professional to follow all your exhausting steps to install all the needed... So the question is: what's the audience?

Comment: @Vani recent foundings that both Firefox and Chrome increased the LocalStorage limit size to 10MB (Found that info for FF on Google and in Chrome by testing the storage limit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to bother your users on how to install some programs in order to store their data while offline - (this process should flow unnoticed or with less pain for the user as possible) I suggest you going for **LocalStorage** -
If you're fine with **10MB** (Chrome and Firefox, **5MB on mobile**) of user disk quota.

Need more space?

***[Cache API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache)*** as an interface of the **[ServiceWorker API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)**

> A service worker is an event-driven worker registered against an origin and a path. It takes the form of a JavaScript file that can control the web page/site it is associated with, intercepting and modifying navigation and resource requests, and caching resources in a very granular fashion to give you complete control over how your app behaves in certain situations (the most obvious one being when the **network is not available**.)

***[IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB)*** :

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Using_IndexedDB
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB
- https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/storing-images-and-files-in-indexeddb/
- https://github.com/jonnysmith1981/getIndexedDbSize **Calculate the IDB size!**

Worth knowing that (FF at least) all IndexedDB bases (from multiple sources/websites) cannot take more than 50% total disk size - and from that size one IDB cannot take up more than 20%. Also, according to *Least Recently Used Policy*, if the databases available space gets full, the browser can (and will) **[kill an IndexedBD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API/Browser_storage_limits_and_eviction_criteria)**.

Note that for **older browsers** that do not support IndexedDB you might want to use a shim to fallback to **[Web SQL Database](http://www.w3.org/TR/webdatabase/)** (which is no longer maintained)

Comment: thanks a lot for this idea! My target audience are non IT-professional and you're right, I don't want to bother them with my instructions.. As for PHP Desktop, they will need to double click on the .exe file to run the app offline. But I'm more concerned about updating when going online.. I'm going through IndexedDB and hope it would meet this criteria.

Comment: @Vani yes, just keep in mind that you'll find IndexedDB a pain in the foobar.  It's quite all newish and still lot of dust around it. Good news is that FF allows you to store even 50MB of data without prompting the user to allow for more space. I'd frankly go for LocalStorage... looot more easier. I'd just keep it smart to fit any interaction under 5MB of records (as suggested in my Q comments). That would be a loooooot of data editing, but less image uploading and stuff with media (Primarily cause an image in Base64 is 4/3 bigger than the original image data.)

Comment: C.Buljan, I take your advice; will go for Localstorage but give a go with IndexedDB for learning purpose. Thank you so much for your time and effort :)

Comment: @Vani sure go for it IndexedDB is asyncronous and terribly fast. It's a bit complicated but worth the knowledge.